# Autofocus form field in overlay

Tags: jquery, html, overlay

This might be really simple, but after hours of searching, I haven't been able to figure it out.

I need to autofocus on a form field inside an overlay, which is opened on a button click.

I'm using the simple jQuery overlay code.

```
$(function() {
    $("a[rel]").overlay();
});
```

The button's code is:

```
<a rel="#popup">Button text</a>
```

And (simplified) the overlay's HTML code is here:

```
<div class="simple-overlay" id="popup">
    <form method="post" class="form-class" action="form-action"  >
        <input class="text" id="email-field" type="text" name="email" value="" />
        <input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="501" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Spokey, who figured out the solution.

I've posted it below in case someone's looking for the answer.

You can also check out a live example here: http://www.petersandeen.com/get-landing-page-checklist/

```
$(function () {
    $(".register-button").overlay({
        mask: '#000000',
        onLoad: function () {
            $('#email-field').focus();
        }
    });
});
```

.register-button is the div class assigned to the button that opens the overlay.

The #email-field is the div id assigned to the form field inside the overlay that's automatically focused when the overlay is opened.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer was updated from the good comments ( @Spokey ) below.*

Start the overlay plugin on ready

```
$(function () {
    $("a[rel]").overlay({ mask: '#000000', onLoad: function(){ $('#email-field').focus();} });
});
```

and leave the `<a>` tags clean without onclick events.

This should be the way to do it.

Comment: To be clear, I added it right after the `$("a[rel]").overlay();` code... Was that the right place?

Comment: @user2245490 well you need to add it right after you're sure the input is visible.

Comment: @user2245490 .overlay loads a page and then displays it, right? So you have the input element only after the load is done. If the loading is asynchronous (as i imagine, never used .overlay) you don't have the element ready after .overlay call. So there must be an event fired when the overlay is displayed. In that event you should call the .focus()

Comment: I think so: it shows a div element that's hidden by default. Any idea how I can make it fire at the right time?

Comment: oh if the div is hidden and it only show it then it must work right after the .overlay() call.  :( do you have a test url to try it?

Comment: try `$("a[rel]").overlay({ onLoad: function(){ $('#email-field').focus(); } });`

Comment: @PaoloCasciello Here's a link: http://www.petersandeen.com/overlay-test-page/ I used the code Spokey added below... But it's not working (though I'm not sure if I'm just not using it right).

Comment: @Spokey Thanks, I tried the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user2245490 you have used the `.overlay()` in 2 or more places. you have in `<a>` an `onclick` function and then in your head you have the code I gave you. You should use only one. Also search to see if you have them anywhere else again.

Comment: @Spokey Thanks, it works! However, there are two problems. First, you need to click the link twice for the overlay to open. How can I make it work with just one click? Second, there's no mask anymore (and I couldn't figure out where in the code I should add it when it used to be in `$(function() {
 $("a[rel]").overlay({mask: '#000'});
});`

Comment: Just got the mask to work, but it still needs two clicks to open... Any thoughts on that are much appreciated.

Comment: can you show on which page? for me it works with one click where I clicked.

Comment: @Spokey Here's a new page with the updated code (and the two-click issue): http://www.petersandeen.com/overlay-testing-page/ Thanks again.

Comment: you do not need to use `onclick='overLayfocus()'` because the `.overlay()` already has a click event. So what you're doing is clicking once to activate `overLayfocus()` then clicking again to activate `.overlay()` and that requires 2 clicks. So don't put `$('ap[rel')` in a function [See this fiddle for changes](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/7PjKg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `autofocus` attribute to your input field:

```
<input class="text" id="email-field" type="text" name="email" value="" autofocus />
```